# How to Add a Custom Button to Admin Sales Order View in Magento2

Tags: magento2

[image]

How to add a custom button to sales order view in magento2, since some of the events was remove in-favor of plugins.

- Removed some events (plugins must be used instead):

  - adminhtml_widget_container_html_before ([use in magento 1.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642599/how-to-add-new-button-to-order-view-in-magento-admin-panel))
  - admin_session_user_logout
  - model_config_data_save_before
  - ...

See [Magento2 Change Log](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.md)

Comment: Custom button on the Order page, https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/add-custom-button-on-order-view-admin-page-magento/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After trying many different ways, this is the only solution I could find that seem to work without affecting other modules. I would love to see other solutions.

**Option 1**

Create a plugin in Company/Module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button\Toolbar">
        <plugin name="MagePal_TestBed::pluginBefore" type="MagePal\TestBed\Plugin\PluginBefore" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Then in Plugin/PluginBefore.php

```
namespace MagePal\TestBed\Plugin;

class PluginBefore
{
    public function beforePushButtons(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button\Toolbar\Interceptor $subject,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button\ButtonList $buttonList
    ) {

        $this->_request = $context->getRequest();
        if($this->_request->getFullActionName() == 'sales_order_view'){
              $buttonList->add(
                'mybutton',
                ['label' => __('My Button'), 'onclick' => 'setLocation(window.location.href)', 'class' => 'reset'],
                -1
            );
        }

    }
}
```

**Option 2**

Create a plugin in Company/Module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="\Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View">
        <plugin name="MagePal_TestBed::pluginBeforeView" type="MagePal\TestBed\Plugin\PluginBeforeView" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Then in Plugin/PluginBeforeView.php

```
namespace MagePal\TestBed\Plugin;

class PluginBeforeView
{

    public function beforeGetOrderId(\Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View $subject){
        $subject->addButton(
                'mybutton',
                ['label' => __('My Buttion'), 'onclick' => 'setLocation(window.location.href)', 'class' => 'reset'],
                -1
            );

        return null;
    }

}
```

See [Full Source code](http://github.com/magepal/stackexchange/tree/develop/91071)

Comment: @r-s I've tried 2nd option, and it causes an error - `Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, object given in D:\new\OpenServer\domains\graffiticaps-m2.loc\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php on line 144`, since __callPlugin() method adds what `beforeGetOrderId()` method returns to arguments of `getOrderId()` method. \vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php [line 124] - `$arguments = $beforeResult;`. So I think there must be returned smth else, but not object, meaning $subject

Comment: I just test on Magento 2.0.2... Take a look at my update for option #2 .... See https://github.com/magepal/stackexchange/tree/develop/91071

Comment: Is there any way to call ajax on click of this button?

Comment: @nuwaus ... you could change the 'onclick' to 'onclick="processAjax()"" then add you ajax function there or some other on click jquery binding

Comment: here is a similar issue. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/251458/m2-how-to-put-button-on-sales-order-information-page

Comment: Using option 2 doesn't allow you to use $this->getOrderId(). Using the plugin as shown in this answer appears to work with it https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/137616/297.

Answer (score 30):

The cleanest solution I've seen so far is to use a plugin targeting 'beforeSetLayout'

This can target the exact block, saving the check for the current request, and also avoids the plugin being on 'getOrderId' which in my case could not be used as I needed to call getOrderId in my plugin method.

So this in di.xml

```
   <type name="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View">
    <plugin name="addMyButton" type="My\Module\Plugin\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View"/>
   </type>
```

And then this in the file My\Module\Plugin\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View.php

```
public function beforeSetLayout(\Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View $view)
{
    $message ='Are you sure you want to do this?';
    $url = $view->getUrl('route_id/path').$view->getOrderId();


    $view->addButton(
        'order_myaction',
        [
            'label' => __('My Action'),
            'class' => 'myclass',
            'onclick' => "confirmSetLocation('{$message}', '{$url}')"
        ]
    );


}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm

Answer (score 10):

Create DI file: `app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/etc/di.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="SalesOrderViewWidgetContext" type="\Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="buttonList" xsi:type="object">YourVendor\YourModule\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\ButtonList
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="context" xsi:type="object">SalesOrderViewWidgetContext</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

What we do here is:

1. Set custom `context` argument into the `Order\View` block. This
   context is defined as a virtual type.
2. Define virtual type for a
   widget context. We set custom `buttonList` argument with our own
   button list class.

Implement your button list class:

```
<?php
namespace YourVendor\YourModule\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View;

class ButtonList extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button\ButtonList
{
   public function __construct(\Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button\ItemFactory $itemFactory)
   {
       parent::__construct($itemFactory);
       $this->add('mybutton', [
           'label' => __('My button label')
       ]);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution ! I think this is the best and the most elegant.

Comment: This looked nice, elegant and easy to understand but unfortunately it does not work. In Magento 2.3.4 when clicking in a order, it throws an error `Exception occurred during order load`

Comment: Thank you working fine for Magento 2.4.3

Answer (score 10):

This is one of the best solutions I have seen so far without using plugins. It is also used by the PayPal module.

**MagePal/CustomButton/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="sales_order_edit">
            <block class="MagePal\CustomButton\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Buttons" name="custom_buttons" />
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**MagePal/CustomButton/Block/Adminhtml/Order/View/Buttons.php**

```
namespace MagePal\CustomButton\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View;
    
class Buttons extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View
{    

   protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();

        if(!$this->getOrderId()) {
            return $this;
        }

        $buttonUrl = $this->_urlBuilder->getUrl(
            'adminhtml/custombutton/new',
            ['order_id' => $this->getOrderId()]
        );

        $this->addButton(
            'create_custom_button',
            ['label' => __('Custom Button'), 'onclick' => 'setLocation(\'' . $buttonUrl . '\')']
        );
        
        return $this;
    }

}
```

Comment: There is mistake in `adminhtml_sales_order_view.xml` should be `sales_order_view.xml`

Comment: There is no need in `public function __construct`

Answer (score 2):

Create di.xml following location

```
app/code/Learning/RewriteSales/etc/di.xml
```

Content should be

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context">
        <plugin name="add_custom_button_sales_veiw" type="Learning\RewriteSales\Plugin\Widget\Context" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Create Context.php following loaction

```
app/code/Learning/RewriteSales/Plugin/Widget/Context.php
```

Content should be

```
namespace Learning\RewriteSales\Plugin\Widget;


class Context
{
    public function afterGetButtonList(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $subject,
        $buttonList
    )
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $request = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context')->getRequest();
        if($request->getFullActionName() == 'sales_order_view'){
            $buttonList->add(
                'custom_button',
                [
                    'label' => __('Custom Button'),
                    'onclick' => 'setLocation(\'' . $this->getCustomUrl() . '\')',
                    'class' => 'ship'
                ]
            );
        }

        return $buttonList;
    }

    public function getCustomUrl()
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $urlManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Url');
        return $urlManager->getUrl('sales/*/custom');
    }
}
```

Clear Magento cache and run update command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, but from all my testing so far `preference` type is the equivalent of rewrite in magento 1. Therefore only one module can take advantage of it

Comment: yes. But you can't create plugin for protected function.

Comment: Just update my answer using plugin

Comment: Instead of loading the objectManager you could have done `$subject->getRequest()->getFullActionName()`

Comment: add this before afterGetButtonList function.......
protected $urlBuider;
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder)
    {
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
    }

Then in getCustomUrl() function add this line only.....
return $this->urlBuilder->getUrl('modulename/controllername/methodname',array('parameter'=>parameter_value));

Comment: Ok, can anyone please tell me, how to get order id in Context.php?

Comment: I got order id using this : $order_id = $request->getParam('order_id');

Comment: how can i call it to custom controller in admin?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below link its working perfect.
[Add a Custom Button to Admin Sales Order View](https://www.magevision.com/blog/post/add-a-custom-button-to-admin-sales-order-view-magento-2)