# Magento2 : How to add Custom button in product edit form

Tags: magento2

I have created one custom module and through that module, I want to add a custom button in Admin product edit form.

I have created a plugin using the below reference
[How to Add a Custom Button to Admin Sales Order View in Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91071/how-to-add-a-custom-button-to-admin-sales-order-view-in-magento2)

**di.xml**

```
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <type name="\Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit">
            <plugin name="Company_Module::pluginBeforeView" type="Company\Module\Plugin\PluginBeforeView" />
        </type>
    </config>
```

**PluginBeforeView.php**

```
namespace Company\Module\Plugin;

class PluginBeforeView
    {

        public function beforeGetOrderId(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit $subject){
            $subject->addButton(
                    'mybutton',
                    ['label' => __('My Buttion'), 'onclick' => 'setLocation(window.location.href)', 'class' => 'reset'],
                    -1
                );

            return null;
        }

    }
```

But it did not work. Any idea how to solve this.

Comment: Please refer this post,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40281868/how-to-add-a-new-button-next-to-the-page-action-buttons-on-the-admin-product-edi
This will not completely solve your problem, but you could get some idea.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Add a Custom Button to Admin Sales Order View in Magento2](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91071/how-to-add-a-custom-button-to-admin-sales-order-view-in-magento2)

Answer (score 9):

The product form is generated via ui-components.
The ui component name for product form is `view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_form.xml`.

You need to create a file with the same name and path in your own module with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="button-unique-identifier-here" xsi:type="string">[Namespace]\[Module]\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button\CustomButton</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</form>
```

Then create the class `[Namespace]\[Module]\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button\CustomButton` in the file `[Namespace]/[Module]/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Edit/Button/CustomButton.php`

```
<?php 
namespace [Namespace]\[Module]\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button;

use Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\GenericButton;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;

class CustomButton extends GenericButton implements ButtonProviderInterface
{
    public function getButtonData()
    {
        return [
            'label' => __('Your button label here'),
            'on_click' => "alert('it works')",
            'sort_order' => 100
        ];
    }
}
```

Your ui component file should be merged with the main file and your buttons should appear among the other buttons.

Comment: Hi Marius, thanks for the answer. But it didn't worked. I have created file product_form.xml under ui_component and CustomButton under CompanyName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button

Comment: I just tested it and it works like a charm. I needed to clean my Magento cache first however.

Comment: How can i give my controller action in on_click section

Comment: it worked great.

Comment: It works, but it also showing on product creation page. How to show to product edit page only? Thanks

Comment: Still working on 2.4.2, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to add a custom button on customers info page in Magento admin but didn't find any related stuff except this helpful thread. Sharing my findings and code customization here.

Customer edit form buttons are defined in `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/base/ui_component/customer_form.xml` as

```
<item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="back" xsi:type="string">Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\BackButton</item>
    <item name="delete" xsi:type="string">Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\DeleteButton</item>
    <item name="invalidateToken" xsi:type="string">Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\InvalidateTokenButton</item>
    <item name="unlock" xsi:type="string">Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\UnlockButton</item>
    <item name="resetPassword" xsi:type="string">Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\ResetPasswordButton</item>
    <item name="order" xsi:type="string">Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\OrderButton</item>
    <item name="reset" xsi:type="string">Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\ResetButton</item>
    <item name="save" xsi:type="string">Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\SaveButton</item>
    <item name="save_and_continue" xsi:type="string">Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\SaveAndContinueButton</item>
</item>
```

Every button has its own Block class.

So to add a new button, we need to extend customer_form.xml. Here are the steps:

**Step 1:** Create a customer edit form at `Vendor\Module\view\base\ui_component\customer_form.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="custom_button" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Button\CustomButton</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</form>
```

**Step 2:** Create a block class to render button at `Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Button\CustomButton.php`

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Button;

use Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\GenericButton;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;

class CustomButton extends GenericButton implements ButtonProviderInterface {

    protected $_customerRepository;

    /**
     * @var AccountManagementInterface
     */
    protected $customerAccountManagement;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param AccountManagementInterface $customerAccountManagement
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context               $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry                         $registry,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface    $customerAccountManagement,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface   $customerRepository
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $registry);
        $this->customerAccountManagement    = $customerAccountManagement;
        $this->_customerRepository          = $customerRepository;
    }

    public function getButtonData()
    {
        $customerId = $this->getCustomerId();

        // get customer
        $customer = $this->_customerRepository->getById($customerId);

        // confirm message
        $message = __('Are you sure you want to do this?');

        if ($customer->getConfirmation())
        {
            return [
                'label' => __('Custom Button'),
                'on_click' => "confirmSetLocation('{$message}', '{$this->getCustomUrl()}')",
                //'on_click' => "alert('Hello')",
                'sort_order' => 100
            ];
        }

        return;
    }

    /**
     * URL getter
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCustomUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('custom/index/custom', ['customer_id' => $this->getCustomerId()]);
    }
}
```

**Step 3:** flush / clean cache and check if Admin panel is showing your custom button on Customer edit form.

Use `'on_click' => "alert('Hello')"` just to ensure that your button is working. Then replace it with `'on_click' => "confirmSetLocation('{$message}', '{$this->getCustomUrl()}')",`

**Step 4:** Create a route for controller action at: `Vendor\Module\etc\adminhtml\routes.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="custom" frontName="custom">
            <module name="Vendor_Module" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**Step 5:** Now define your controller action to perform something on button click. Controller path is `Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Custom.php`

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

use Magento\Integration\Api\CustomerTokenServiceInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Address\Mapper;
use Magento\Framework\DataObjectFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper;

class Custom extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index
{
    protected $_accountManagement;
    protected $_customerRepository;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory $addressFactory
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\FormFactory $formFactory
     * @param \Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriberFactory $subscriberFactory
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Helper\View $viewHelper
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Math\Random $random
     * @param CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataObjectConverter $extensibleDataObjectConverter
     * @param Mapper $addressMapper
     * @param AccountManagementInterface $customerAccountManagement
     * @param AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository
     * @param CustomerInterfaceFactory $customerDataFactory
     * @param AddressInterfaceFactory $addressDataFactory
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer\Mapper $customerMapper
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Reflection\DataObjectProcessor $dataObjectProcessor
     * @param DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper
     * @param DataObjectFactory $objectFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory $layoutFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory $resultLayoutFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory $addressFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriberFactory $subscriberFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Helper\View $viewHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\Math\Random $random,
        CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataObjectConverter $extensibleDataObjectConverter,
        Mapper $addressMapper,
        AccountManagementInterface $customerAccountManagement,
        AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository,
        CustomerInterfaceFactory $customerDataFactory,
        AddressInterfaceFactory $addressDataFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer\Mapper $customerMapper,
        \Magento\Framework\Reflection\DataObjectProcessor $dataObjectProcessor,
        DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper,
        DataObjectFactory $objectFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory $layoutFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory $resultLayoutFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
    ) {
        $this->_accountManagement   = $customerAccountManagement;
        $this->_customerRepository  = $customerRepository;
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $coreRegistry,
            $fileFactory,
            $customerFactory,
            $addressFactory,
            $formFactory,
            $subscriberFactory,
            $viewHelper,
            $random,
            $customerRepository,
            $extensibleDataObjectConverter,
            $addressMapper,
            $customerAccountManagement,
            $addressRepository,
            $customerDataFactory,
            $addressDataFactory,
            $customerMapper,
            $dataObjectProcessor,
            $dataObjectHelper,
            $objectFactory,
            $layoutFactory,
            $resultLayoutFactory,
            $resultPageFactory,
            $resultForwardFactory,
            $resultJsonFactory
        );
    }

    /**
     * custom action handler
     *
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        if ($customerId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('customer_id')) {
            try {

                // get customer
                $customer = $this->_customerRepository->getById($customerId);

                // do something here
                // put your code here

                // add message
                $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('You have done this.'));

                // redirect
                $resultRedirect->setPath('customer/index/edit', ['id' => $customerId, '_current' => true]);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
                $resultRedirect->setPath('customer/index/edit', ['id' => $customerId, '_current' => true]);
            }
        } else {
            $this->messageManager->addError(__('We can\'t find a customer to perform this action'));
            $resultRedirect->setPath('customer/index/index');
        }
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
```