# Magento2 : How to add Custom button [draft] in Product Edit form

Tags: admin, magento-2.1

[image]

I want add a new *Draft* button in Product Edit page (located between **Back and Add Attribute**)

I am able to add by following the tutorial : [magento2-how-to-add-custom-button-in-product-edit-form](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/138437/magento2-how-to-add-custom-button-in-product-edit-form)

But, I am unable to add the link to my custom controller.
Does anyone have any advice please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento2 : How to add Custom button in product edit form](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/138437/magento2-how-to-add-custom-button-in-product-edit-form)

Comment: I am able to added Teja i want add link to my controller can you please tell me

Answer (score 0):

The product form is generated via ui-components.
The ui component name for product form is `view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_form.xml`.

You need to create a file with the same name and path in your own module with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="button-unique-identifier-here" xsi:type="string">[Namespace]\[Module]\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button\CustomButton</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</form>
```

Then create the class `[Namespace]\[Module]\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button\CustomButton` in the file `[Namespace]/[Module]/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Edit/Button/CustomButton.php`

```
<?php 
namespace [Namespace]\[Module]\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button;

use Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button\Generic;

class CustomButton extends Generic
{
    public function getButtonData()
    {
        return [
            'label' => __('Enter Your button label here'),
            'on_click' => "alert('it works..')",
            'class' => 'primary',
            'sort_order' => 100
        ];
    }
}
```

Your ui component file should be merged with the main file and your buttons should appear among the other buttons.

Comment: Sorry to ask, may you please have a look at my question related to this, regarding a button implementation. 
 https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/339727/magento-2-admin-menu-buttons-uicomponent-buttons-behaviour . In short, I want to know if there is any built-in behaviour.