# Magento 2 Admin Menu buttons (UiComponent buttons) behaviour

Tags: magento2.3, uicomponent, ui-form, admin-controller

## Question

What do I need to setup a Button's behaviour, or is there CRUD built-in Magento 2 behaviour when I do not specify a Controller?

> This is [The tutorial article](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/create-admin-grid-magento-2.html) I am following.

> I found the github [The sample module](https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-sample-module/) that seems to be based on the tutorial.

> This is [The UI compontent config file](https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-sample-module/blob/master/view/adminhtml/ui_component/mageplaza_helloworld_post_listing.xml) I am basing my module on.

The relevant section on the 'Add New Post' button `(name='add')`:

```
<item name="add" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Post</item>
    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
    <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/new</item>
</item>
```

The target defined there is `*/*/new`.

I have managed to get the grid working, it shows the `InstallSchema/UpgradeSchema` changes correctly in the database and in the admin area.

However, it feels like the tutorial isn't explaining everything here.  The referenced `*/*/new` resolves to `admin/mymoduleroute/user/new`

Are there built-in CRUD control handlers ? Like when I press 'New', it uses built-in functionality.  As explained, the tutorial doesn't show the Controller part relevant to this (as far as I can see).

I also see this in log file right now:

```
 Request validation failed for action "Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward\Interceptor"
 {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\InvalidRequestException(code: 0):
 Invalid request received at /var/www/html/vendor/magento/
module-backend/App/Request/BackendValidator.php:152)"}
```

Isn't interceptors supposed to built automatically by Magento 2?

***I am not in production mode.***

Comment: I would really appreciate some assistance :)

Comment: Same issue here M2.4.2