# How to add custom dropdown button to Admin Sales Order View in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, sales-order, admin-panel

I've followed [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91071/how-to-add-a-custom-button-to-admin-sales-order-view-in-magento2) link to add custom button in Admin Sales Order View in Magento 2, and it works great. Now I want to replace this button with 3 dropdown options button. Something like changing store scope in Admin Panel. I want this 3 buttons to run same controller method with different parameters.
How can i achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works for me , try to look splitButton

```
class ViewPlugin
{

    public function beforeSetLayout(
        MagentoView $view,
        LayoutInterface $layout
    ) {
       
        $addButtonProps = [
            'id' => 'test',
            'label' => __('Test'),
            'class' => 'add',
            'button_class' => '',
            'class_name' => 'Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button\SplitButton',
            'options' => $this->getCustomActionListOptions(),
        ];
        $view->addButton('test',$addButtonProps);
    }

    protected function getCustomActionListOptions()
    {
        /*list of button which you want to add*/
        $splitButtonOptions=[
            'action_1'=>['label'=>__('Action 1'),'onclick'=>'setLocation("ACTION 1")'],
            'action_2'=>['label'=>__('Action 2'),'onclick'=>'setLocation("ACTION 2")'],
            'action_3'=>['label'=>__('Action 3'),'onclick'=>'setLocation("ACTION 3")']
        ];
        
        return $splitButtonOptions;
    }

}
```

```
 <type name="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View">
    <plugin name="addMyButton" type="My\Module\Plugin\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View"/>
   </type>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Today or tomorrow i will try and let you know :)

Comment: after i wrote above comment i realized that it uses the same plugin. So i tested and it works :D thanks, and also thanks for information that this is split button :D

Answer (score 0):

I have created it by calling
sales_order_view.xml
first create sales_order_view.xml in vendor/module/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="sales_order_edit">
            <block class="vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Buttons" name="custom_buttons" />
        </referenceBlock> 
    </body>
</page>

Answer (score -1):

```
namespace vendor\module\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View;

class Buttons extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View
{    

   protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();

        if(!$this->getOrderId()) {
            return $this;
        }      

        $addButtonProps = [
            'id' => 'stocksheet',
            'label' => __('Shocksheet'),
            'class' => 'add',
            'button_class' => '',
            'class_name' => 'Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button\SplitButton',
            'options' => $this->getCustomActionListOptions(),
        ];
        $this->addButton('test',$addButtonProps);
        
        return $this;
    }

    protected function getCustomActionListOptions()
    {
        $csvUrl = $this->_urlBuilder->getUrl(
            'vestocksheet/index',
            ['order_id' => $this->getOrder()->getIncrementId()]
        );

        /*list of button which you want to add*/
        $splitButtonOptions=[
            'csv'=>['label'=>__('CSV'),'onclick' => 'setLocation(\'' . $csvUrl . '\')'],
            'pdf'=>['label'=>__('PDF'),'onclick' => 'setLocation(\'' . $csvUrl . '\')']
        ];
        return $splitButtonOptions;
    }

}
```