# Admin order page: add print button

Tags: magento2, admin, adminhtml, custom, print

I found almost how the print button is created on the invoice page (invoked from `vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/widget/button.phtml`) with the debug option in Magento2. I would like to add in directly on the order page to avoid going to the invoice page each time. I can't find the exact code that need to be added to my custom `adminhtml` to add it.

I would like to find how to add the function who generate this code :

```
<button id="print" title="Print" type="button" class="action-default scalable print" onclick="setLocation('MAGENTO_URL/admin/sales/order_invoice/print/invoice_id/ID/')" data-ui-id="sales-invoice-view-print-button">
    <span>Print</span>
</button>
```

If possible to add like after the `view` link or as a button on the order information tab since I already have some custom code for this page:

[image: tab invoice]

Thanks in advance

Comment: you want to add custom button  into invoice grid ?

Comment: Can be nice like the `view` one in the action column. A button can work too in a new column.

Comment: It is possible add image. you what want to

Comment: I added some details about where I want to add the code

Comment: Please share your action columns code

Comment: It's the default one. I didn't edit it since I can't find how override it yet too. Can you indicate what is the file?

Comment: you create new columns and call your link.

Comment: Do you have a link or example for doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working using some code provide from another post:  [How to Add a Custom Button to Admin Sales Order View in Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91071/how-to-add-a-custom-button-to-admin-sales-order-view-in-magento2).

Didn't find for the action link but working for adding a new button.